# Geoserver WPS process list enabling /disabling through functionality code provided by geoserver WEBINF/lib

Tags: geoserver, geoprocessing, wps

How can i enable or disable WPS processes through functionality code, i haven't found that related functionality code in geoserver WPS extension jar files those are in WEBINF/lib. Please guide me the specific location of WPS process functionality and enabling and disabling process